# Culture error when loading subscriptions, SSRS 2016

Tags: ssrs, sql-server-2016

When attempting to load subscriptions in Sql Reporting Services 2016 users are receiving this error:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!5f!05/31/2019-16:15:48::
>   e ERROR: [vby5m1jr]: OData exception occurred:
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture.  Make sure
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
>   at
>   System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String
>   fileName)    at
>   System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean
>   createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.Keys.GetString(String
>   key)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.get_MissingEndpoint()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.MissingEndpointException..ctor(Exception
>   inner)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.MissingEndpointException.ThrowIfEndpointMissing(WebException
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean
>   setConnectionProtocol)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.GetItemParameters(String
>   itemPath, String historyId, Boolean forRendering, ParameterValue[]
>   values, DataSourceCredentials[] credentials)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.<>c__DisplayClassa.<GetItemParameters>b__9()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithWindowsAuth[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol
>   soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithCorrespondingAuthMechanism[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol
>   soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.GetItemParameters(IPrincipal
>   userPrincipal, String itemPath, String historyId, Boolean
>   forRendering, ParameterValue[] values, DataSourceCredentials[]
>   credentials)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.GetParameterTypes(IPrincipal
>   userPrincipal, String reportpath)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.SubscriptionService.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetSubscriptions>b__0(SubscriptionImpl
>   x)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.SubscriptionsController.GetEntitySet(String
>   castName)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.Reflection.EntitySetReflectionODataController`1.GetRoot(ODataPath
>   oDataPath, Int32& index)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.Reflection.ReflectionODataController`1.Get(ODataPath
>   oDataPath)    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext().
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!59!05/31/2019-16:15:48::
>   i INFO: [vby5m1jr]: 10.80.28.51: GET /api/v1.0/subscriptions -
>   Response 500 - 0:00:00.152451

We are running SSRS as a virtual service account and I temporarily granted 'Everyone' full access to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files to rule out permissions errors. I'm stumped. Users can not load existing subscriptions nor can they add new ones. I noticed that there is not an 'en' folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\RSWebApp.